# ngStyle attribute and $interval issue in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make the background picture of my app dynamic by using the ng-style directive but its producing weird results. The body tag looks like this

```
<body ng-controller='MyCtrl' ng-style="{'background-image': getImage()}">
<div id='dateToday'>
    {{dateToday | date:'medium'}}
    </div>
</body>
```

This is the getImage function

```
$scope.getImage = function(){
  var backgrounds = ["url(app/img/butterfly.jpg)", "url(app/img/chicago.jpg)", "url(app/img/car.jpg)", "url(app/img/pug.jpg)", "url(app/img/tree.jpg)"];

      var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*backgrounds.length);
      var y = backgrounds[x];
      return y}
```

When i tested this alone, it worked by giving a new background image each time the page is loaded, but when I try to then use the $interval function to update a date in the same page, the page keeps reloading again and again producing the not so pleasant result on updating the background image every second. this is the set interval function i am using

```
$interval(function(){
$scope.dateToday = Date.parse(new Date());
}, 1000);
```

I am simply using this to refresh the date display on the page, in div dateToday shown above

Comment: Is the issue for the background image or the date? Can you please explain a bit more of the specific issue you have and the desired outcome

Comment: What happen if `backgrounds[x]` x will be 10?

Comment: the issue is with the background image changing every second but the cause seems to be because there is an independent interval function action in the same page

Comment: if you want set `background` only once not use function `getImage` in view, just set var like `$scope.bg=getImage();` and use it instead `{'background-image': bg}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular function [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) by default

> invoke fn within the $apply block.

So when calling $apply - all variables and functions inside view will be recalculated, so and your `getImage` too, and background is change

To avoid this behavior - you can use simple variables like inside controllers

```
$scope.bg = getImage();
```

and in markup

```
<body ng-controller='MyCtrl' ng-style="{'background-image': bg}">
```

in this case background will be change only when controller start

Comment: Thanks, this worked, I created $scope.bg = $scope.getImage() in the controller and passed bg in the view like you showed